# How to integrate git bash in visual studio code on Window

Tags: bash, git, visual-studio-code, terminal

I have installed both visual studio code and git bash on a custom directory in my `C:\users\myname\vsc`, and `C:\users\myname\git` folder.
So for some reason, visual studio code is not able to detect git bash terminal when I click 
 on `Terminal > Select default Profile`.

I tried to add this to add bash as a new terminal

```json
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Users\\myname\\github\\bin\\bash.exe"
```

but vsc is saying that this setting is deprecated so I tried this after reading its [documentation page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal).

```json
{    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "Bash": {
            "source": "Git Bash",
        }
    }
}
```

but this is also not working, **so how I can solve this issue?**

Comment: I had the same issue and I fixed it by reinstalling git to the default path. My VS Code files were installed to the default path (`C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code`), but I installed git to a different path (`E:\Git`). All I did was to reinstall git to the default path (`C:\Program Files\Git`) and Git Bash is now visible to my VS Code. Got that solution here if you want to know more https://dev.to/jemengullo/comment/1gakp

Comment: Yeah you are right, I had to do that same

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall git for windows into the default location, relaunch VSCode and Git bash will appear on your Launch Profile.

This works for me even with touching the settings.json.